# How to send Gyroscope data by socket connection

Tags: android, sockets

I want to use my mobile as a steering wheel. For this, I take de gyroscope info, this party it's done.

The problem is when I try to send this data by socket conecction. Because I can't do this on the main thread.

Anyone knows how to implement this?

Get gyroscope data -> send data by socket.

PD: Anyone knows any open source app, that already do this?

Thanks all.

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a well documented framework like SocketRocket (iOS) https://github.com/square/SocketRocket or Android Async (Android) https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync and handle it with a NodeJS backend to do whatever you like. Both are extremely well documented and would be well suited to your use case.

I think you will have a difficult time finding something open source that does what you specifically want it to do. Take a look at those libraries (both support sockets) and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Create socket in a separate thread:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
InputStream inputStream;
OutputStream outputStream;

socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IP_TO_CONNECT_TO,PORT),TIMEOUT);
inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
```

Then you can send data in main thread if you want. To send "test" for example:

```
os.write("test".getBytes());
```